# How to store points (from point cloud) as a glTF file

Tags: python, pandas, gltf

I have a pandas dataframe with columns x,y,z,r,g,b
Where each row is a point. The x,y and z are the position of the point. And the r,g and b the color (as red, green and blue)

I now would like to store these points as a glTF file using Python.

Online I could find some resources how to convert the pointcloud to a mesh and store that. But I would like to store the points in the glTF directly without converting to a mesh.

According to this [link](https://portal.ogc.org/files/102132#toc24) specifying 3D tiles this should be possible for version 2.0 and higher.

Does anyone know anyone know how to do this in practice?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around using the 3d-tiles-tools node package. A pure Python solution would be better, but this at least works.

```
#npm install 3d-tiles-tools
import pygltflib
import subprocess

file = 'mesh_192089.b3dm'
file_out = '/home/daniel/extracted.glb'
cmd = 'npx 3d-tiles-tools i3dmToGlb -i /home/daniel/' + file + ' -o ' + file_out
status = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8", "replace")

with open(file_out, 'rb') as c:
    fileStream = c.read()
gltf = pygltflib.GLTF2.load_from_bytes(fileStream)
```